# Add link to Google Chart via select handler

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, selection, linechart

I tried to open a link in a Google line chart via the selection handler. For some reason my chart stops rendering and I am not really sure why (javascript newbie...).

This is where the code is loaded in my html:

```
<pre><code><script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript">
Hier den Javascript-Code aus dem unteren Panel einfügen um das Script direkt im Artikel auszuführen
</script>-->
<div id="tt_6_annotation" style="width: 100%; min-height: 300px; height:auto;"></div></pre></code>
```

This is my code:

```
    google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Monat');
  dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Bewerber');
  dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Stellenangebote');
  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'string',
    role: 'tooltip',
    p: {
      html: true // um CSS zu verwenden muss html:true gesetzt werden
    },
  });
  dataTable.addColumn({
  type: 'string',
  role: 'selection',
  }); //um direkt aus dem Datatable mit einem Klick auf einen Knotenpunkt über den select Handler einen Link zu öffnen

  dataTable.addRows([
    ['Jan', 1.370828308, 1.217768314, 'Stuff in my Tooltip', '168184',],
 ['Feb', 1.383085819, 1.28813154387171, 'Stuff in my Tooltip', '168185',],
        ]);


  var options = {
    title: 'Arbeitsmarkt Gesamt 2016 (Knotenpunkt anklicken um Links aufzurufen)',
    titleTextStyle: {fontSize: 20,},
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: 'bottom',
    colors: ['#2646ad', '#f56e12'],
    format: 'decimal',
    lineWidth: 3,
    tooltip: {
      isHtml: true,
      trigger: 'both', //both erlaubt es beim Klick auf den Knotenpunkt den Tooltip zu behalten, so dass man den Link anklicken kann
    },
    vAxis: {
      minValue: 0, // Damit das Diagramm bei 0 beginnt und nicht in einem näheren Bereich
      /*scaleType: 'log', // setzt einen Bereich, der sich um die vorhanden Punkte herum befindet*/
    },
    /*hAxis: {  
    slantedText: true, 
    slantedTextAngle: 30 // um die Beschriftung der x-Achse zu kippen (geht bis 180°) 
},
*/
  };

  var formatter1 = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern:'#.##'});
formatter1.format(dataTable, 1);
  var formatter2 = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern:'#.##'});
formatter2.format(dataTable, 2);



  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('tt_6_annotation'));
  chart.draw(dataTable, options);


  //Bad boy isn't working as it should
  // a click handler which grabs some values then redirects the page
  var google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function(){
  // grab a few details before redirecting
      var selection = chart.getSelection();
      var row = selection[0].row;
      var col = selection[0].column;
      var link = data.getValue(row, 4);
      location.href = 'http://www.mywebsite.de/' + row;
    });  


}
```

This is the part that isn't working. It should get the number in the dataTable, that is a part of the link and add it to my url, which is part of my select.-function:

```
/ a click handler which grabs some values then redirects the page
  var google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function(){
  // grab a few details before redirecting
      var selection = chart.getSelection();
      var row = selection[0].row;
      var col = selection[0].column;
      var link = data.getValue(row, 4);
      location.href = 'http://www.karriere.de/' + row;
    });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, need to verify a selection exists

the `'select'` event is fired when an item is selected AND unselected

verify the selection exists, before accessing the array elements

see following snippet...

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function(){
  var selection = chart.getSelection();
  if (selection.length > 0) {
    var row = selection[0].row;
    var col = selection[0].column;
    var link = dataTable.getValue(row, 4);
    location.href = 'http://www.karriere.de/' + link;
  }
});
```

also, no [data role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#what-roles-are-available) exists for `'selection'` (last column)

```
dataTable.addColumn({
  type: 'string',
  role: 'selection',  // <-- should probably be 'label' instead
});
```

Comment: Thank you, the code runs now without a problem, but the selection handler isn't called -_-

Comment: changed first snippet above --> `data` should have been `dataTable`

Comment: Thank you, I am obviously blinde! Thank you, now everything is working. :D